# problema con CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' o "load failed"

Tags: javascript, html, nodejs, express, cors

```
'--este es el codigo de index.js--'

import  express  from "express";
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';


//Fix para __direname
import path from 'path';
import {fileURLToPath} from 'url';
const __dirname = path.dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url));
import {methods as authentication} from "./controllers/authentication.controller.js"
import {methods as authorization} from "./middlewares/authorization.js";

//Server
const app = express();
app.set("port",4000);
app.listen(app.get("port"));
console.log("Servidor corriendo en puerto",app.get("port"));

//Configuración
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser())


//Rutas
app.get("/",authorization.soloPublico, (req,res)=> res.sendFile(__dirname + "/pages/login.html"));
app.get("/register",authorization.soloPublico,(req,res)=> res.sendFile(__dirname + "/pages/register.html"));
app.get("/admin",authorization.soloAdmin,(req,res)=> res.sendFile(__dirname + "/pages/admin/admin.html"));
app.post("/api/login",authentication.login);
app.post("/api/register",authentication.register);
```

en el primer parte del codigo hace la conexion se establesen rutas y se tra de poder importa todo lo paquetes necesarios para mla ejecuacio de la web.

```
--este es el codigo de register.js---


const mensajeError = document.getElementsByClassName("error")[0];

document.getElementById("register-form").addEventListener("submit", async(e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(e.target.children.user.value)
    const res = await fetch("http://localhost:4000/api/register", {
        method:"POST",
        headers:{
            
            "Content-Type" : "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            user: e.target.children.user.value ,
            email: e.target.children.email.value,
            password: e.target.children.password.value
        })
    })
    if(!res.ok) return mensajeError.classList.toggle("escondido", false);
    const resJson = await res.json();
    if(resJson.redirect){
        window.location.href = resJson.redirect;
    }
})
```

en el este código establezco a registro se configuren la datos se pueda obtener tener y se estabes un comunicacion con fecth de la respuiesta

```
--este es el codigo de login.js--


const mesajeError = document.getElementsByClassName("error")[0]

document.getElementById("login-form").addEventListener("submit", async (e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    const user = e.target.children.user.value;
    const password = e.target.children.password.value;
    const res = await fetch("http://localhost:4000/api/login",{
        method:"POST",
        headers:{
            "Content-Type" : "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            user,password
        })
    });
    if(!res.ok) return mesajeError.classList.toggle("escondido", false);
    const resJson = await res.json();
    if(resJson.redirect){
        window.location.href = resJson.redirect;
    }
})
```

en el este código establezco a login se configuren la datos se pueda obtener tener y se estabes un comunicacion con fecth de la respuiesta

```
--este es el codigo de admin.js--

document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].addEventListener("click",()=>{
  document.cookie ='jwt=; Path=/; Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
  document.location.href = "/"
})
```

en el este código establezco a autorización  se configuren la datos se pueda obtener tener y se estabas un comunicación con los middlewares para poder verifica q usuario puede pasar o no haber la información

```
--este es el codigo de authorization.js--


import jsonwebtoken from "jsonwebtoken";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import {usuarios} from "./../controllers/authentication.controller.js";

dotenv.config();

function soloAdmin(req,res,next){
  const logueado = revisarCookie(req);
  if(logueado) return next();
  return res.redirect("/")
}

function soloPublico(req,res,next){
  const logueado = revisarCookie(req);
  if(!logueado) return next();
  return res.redirect("/admin")
}

function revisarCookie(req){
  try{
    const cookieJWT = req.headers.cookie.split("; ").find(cookie => cookie.startsWith("jwt=")).slice(4);
    const decodificada = jsonwebtoken.verify(cookieJWT,process.env.JWT_SECRET);
    console.log(decodificada)
    const usuarioAResvisar = usuarios.find(usuario => usuario.user === decodificada.user);
    console.log(usuarioAResvisar)
    if(!usuarioAResvisar){
      return false
    }
    return true;
  }
  catch{
    return false;
  }
}


export const methods = {
  soloAdmin,
  soloPublico,
}
```

en el este código establezco a autorización  se configuren la datos se pueda obtener tener y se estabas un comunicación con los middlewares para poder verifica q usuario puede pasar o no haber la información

```
--este es el codigo de authentication.controller.js--


import bcryptjs from "bcryptjs";
import jsonwebtoken from "jsonwebtoken";
import dotenv from "dotenv";

dotenv.config();

export const usuarios = [{
  user: "a",
  email: "a@a.com",
  password: "$2a$05$nLY2It8riku2vwwDIINdgO/XIyPXRg1Gn9LFgnhwKqC4TwcAwEUL2"
}]


async function login(req,res){
  console.log(req.body);
  const user = req.body.user;
  const password = req.body.password;
  if(!user || !password){
    return res.status(400).send({status:"Error",message:"Los campos están incompletos"})
  }
  const usuarioAResvisar = usuarios.find(usuario => usuario.user === user);
  if(!usuarioAResvisar){
    return res.status(400).send({status:"Error",message:"Error durante login"})
  }
  const loginCorrecto = await bcryptjs.compare(password,usuarioAResvisar.password);
  if(!loginCorrecto){
    return res.status(400).send({status:"Error",message:"Error durante login"})
  }
  const token = jsonwebtoken.sign(
    {user:usuarioAResvisar.user},
    process.env.JWT_SECRET,
    {expiresIn:process.env.JWT_EXPIRATION});

    const cookieOption = {
      expires: new Date(Date.now() + process.env.JWT_COOKIE_EXPIRES * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000),
      path: "/"
    }
    res.cookie("jwt",token,cookieOption);
    res.send({status:"ok",message:"Usuario loggeado",redirect:"/admin"});
}

async function register(req,res){
  const user = req.body.user;
  const password = req.body.password;
  const email = req.body.email;
  if(!user || !password || !email){
    return res.status(400).send({status:"Error",message:"Los campos están incompletos"})
  }
  const usuarioAResvisar = usuarios.find(usuario => usuario.user === user);
  if(usuarioAResvisar){
    return res.status(400).send({status:"Error",message:"Este usuario ya existe"})
  }
  const salt = await bcryptjs.genSalt(5);
  const hashPassword = await bcryptjs.hash(password,salt);
  const nuevoUsuario ={
    user, email, password: hashPassword
  }
  usuarios.push(nuevoUsuario);
  console.log(usuarios);
  return res.status(201).send({status:"ok",message:`Usuario ${nuevoUsuario.user} agregado`,redirect:"/"})
}

export const methods = {
  login,
  register
}
```

en esta código se establecen la dependencias de la web para poder trabajar en al mismo

```
--este es el codigo de package.json--


{
  "name": "tienda",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app/index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon --exec node app/index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.20.2",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.6",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.4.1",
    "eruda": "^3.0.1",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "express-session": "^1.18.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^3.0.3"
  }
}
```

```
-- este el codigo de .env---

JWT_SECRET=textosecretoDECIFRADO
JWT_EXPIRATION=7d
JWT_COOKIE_EXPIRES=1
```

este código de prueba para poder ayudar a mi conociento y poder aprender mas el código lo corre en consola cmd con npm rum dev el se ejecuta normalmente en el computador en el navegador por el localhost pero en el mismo instante trato de córrelo en el navegador de mi celular el carga la interfaz grafica pero en el momento de loguear me no  se puede, sale en la consola de navegador del celular "load failed" o tambien CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' me podrian ayudar, gracias.

Comment: Antes de pedir ayuda lo correcto es investigar un poco. Lo que te está pasando es que no tienes CORS configurado con lo cual la única IP válida para tu backend es la suya propia, por eso cuando entras al navegador en la misma máquina que ejecuta el servidor todo va bien (misma IP) pero en cuanto intentas acceder desde otra IP diferente (la de tu móvil) te da error. Buscando en google "cors + express" salen un montón de enlaces que sirven para corregir este error... asumo que no lo has intentado antes de crear la pregunta. Enlaces con info sobre cómo preguntar: [ask], [tour], [help]

Comment: @Benito-B IP+Puerto... misma IP, distinto puerto, CORS

Comment: Pero el puerto no es opcional, si estás sirviendo la aplicación en el puerto 4200 e intentas entrar al 4201 no vas a tener error de CORS, simplemente no vas a encontrar la aplicación ahí, no @gbianchi?

Comment: si tu front esta en localhost:80 y tu back en localhost:4000 vas a tener problemas de cors... @Benito-B

Comment: Usas ExpressJS y no veo que estés usando o estableciendo las cabeceras CORS. Existe un paquete en `npm` para NodeJS que lo hace muy sencillo, se llama, como no, [`cors`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors). Te va a permitir configurar las cabeceras que necesitas.